# What is the meaning of adoc mode?

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, slime, minor-mode

The adoc minor mode automatically appear whenever I open Common Lisp extension file *.lsp.

I have done a search on Google, as well on Emacs help itself, but could not find my wanted information. Thank for any help ;)

[image]

Comment: It's [slime autodoc minor-mode](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/slime_002dautodoc_002dmode.html).

Comment: I see now. Thanks man!

Answer (score 7):

To get help about the current modes: <kbd>c-h m</kbd>

Then search for adoc:

> Eldoc minor mode (indicator **adoc**):
>
> Toggle echo area display of Lisp objects at point (ElDoc mode).
>   With a prefix argument ARG, enable ElDoc mode if ARG is positive,
>   and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable ElDoc mode
>   if ARG is omitted or nil.
>
> ElDoc mode is a buffer-local minor mode.  When enabled, the echo
>   area displays information about a function or variable in the
>   text where point is.  If point is on a documented variable, it
>   displays the first line of that variable’s doc string.  Otherwise
>   it displays the argument list of the function called in the
>   expression point is on.

This is coming through SLIME's [autodoc-mode](https://github.com/slime/slime/blob/master/contrib/slime-autodoc.el) contribution.

Comment: Hi @Rainer Joswig,
Thank you for showing the way to search for help.